# How to run multiple Scheduler within single Windows Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I'm new to windows service. I had created a windows service which has multiple Scheduler. Each Scheduler should run in different time interval. Please help me to know whether it will work within single WS.

my code is here.

```
 private Timer Schedular1;
 private Timer Schedular2;
 public void ScheduleService()
    {
        try
        {
            Schedular1 = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SchedularCallback1));
            Schedular2 = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SchedularCallback2));
            this.WriteToFile("Simple Service Mode: " + mode + " {0}");

            //Set the Default Time.
            DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.MinValue;


            //Get the Scheduled Time from AppSettings.
            scheduledTime = DateTime.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScheduledTime"]);
            if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTime)
            {
                //If Scheduled Time is passed set Schedule for the next day.
                scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddDays(1);
            }



            TimeSpan timeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            string schedule = string.Format("{0} day(s) {1} hour(s) {2} minute(s) {3} seconds(s)", timeSpan.Days, timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);

            this.WriteToFile("Simple Service scheduled to run after: " + schedule + " {0}");

            //Get the difference in Minutes between the Scheduled and Current Time.
            int dueTime1 = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
            int dueTime2 = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds) + 100000;

            //Change the Timer's Due Time.
            Schedular1.Change(dueTime1, Timeout.Infinite);
            Schedular2.Change(dueTime2, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToFile("Simple Service Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

            //Stop the Windows Service.
            using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("SimpleService"))
            {
                serviceController.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

     private void SchedularCallback1(object e)
    {
        this.WriteToFile("I'm in SchedularCallback1");
        this.ScheduleService();
    }

     private void SchedularCallback2(object e)
    {
        this.WriteToFile("I'm in SchedularCallback2");
        this.ScheduleService();
    }
```

I want to know that whether this Scheduler1,Scheduler2 will work correctly without any problems?